# Open File after creating PDF

Tags: android, file, pdf, android-asynctask

I'm using webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobname) to print a PDF using a custom class called PDFPrint. Here an extract of the  class Below:

```
public PdfPrint(PrintAttributes p_atributos, aperturador_archivos mi_aperturador )
{
    atributos = p_atributos;
    aperturador = mi_aperturador;
}

public void print(final PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter, final File path, final String filename)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        printAdapter.onLayout(null, atributos, null, new PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutFinished(PrintDocumentInfo info, boolean changed) {
                printAdapter.onWrite(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES},getOutputFile(path,filename),new CancellationSignal(), new PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages) {
                        super.onWriteFinished(pages);
                    }
                });
            }
        },null);


    }
}

    private ParcelFileDescriptor getOutputFile(File path, String fileName) {
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(path, fileName);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This class is used  by my Activity with this method:

```
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {
        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
        PrintAttributes attributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
                .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("pdf", "pdf", 600, 600))
                .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).build();
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/PDFHYC/");
        PdfPrint pdfPrint = new PdfPrint(attributes, this);
        String[] titulo_split = mToolbar.getTitle().toString().split(" ");
        pdfPrint.print(webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName) , path, titulo_split[0]+ "_"+  titulo_split[1]+ "_" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()).substring(1,6)+ ".pdf");
    }
```

The code works as intended when generating the PDF file. But I want to open the file after has been generated, but I can't find the correct way to do so, I've tried overriding some methods but I get an empty pdf file with no content.

I want to know how can I implement that functionality, here my code for opening the file:

```
public void abrir_pdf(String ruta) {
        File file = new File(ruta);
        Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(data, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Answer (score 0):

My implementation is based upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/5339154) :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
              FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                        pdfFile),
                "application/pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        Intent chooserIntent =
                Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.open_with));

        try {
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            showError(R.string.error_missed_pdf_reader);
        }
```